# How to detect css functions support?

Tags: css

I want to be able to detect if the browser supports specific CSS mathematical functions like mod(), exp(), sqrt(), etc. (currently only supported by Firefox and Safari)

I tried using javascript `CSS.supports('--myVar','mod(7,2)')` but that always returns true for variables.

I also tried experimenting directly in CSS using `@supports` at-rule but that only works for properties.

Answer (score 1):

Use a normal property that accepts the value of the function to check.

```js
CSS.supports('line-height', 'mod(7, 2)')

// or

CSS.supports('line-height: mod(7, 2)')
```

#### Chromium

[image]

#### Firefox

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried experimenting directly in CSS using @supports at-rule but that only works for properties.

This is not true. It works for the property and the value used. The browser needs to recognize both of them.

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}

@supports (opacity: mod(1, 1)) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```